# Frame an update query dynamically using JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am migrating from MyBatis to JPA. I am having issues with JPA update. The object that I am trying to update has 51 fields, so I cannot use @Query. For some api calls, we just get 2 fields to be updated, but jpa save has all values in it because the DTO has those 2 values and rest as NULL. Is there a way to write a query based on incoming values that is not null.
Ex UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = Alfred Schmidt, City= Frankfurt WHERE CustomerID = 1;
while DTO has other 49 fields as null